# Linkedin App - Getting "Internal error occurred, please try again later."

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to create a linkedin app at https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps/new.  I'm putting all the data in and keeping it short (another Stackoverflow question had mention of making things short) and I've tried changing things in the initial page, including company, names, URL's, etc, etc and it always tell me

Internal error occurred, please try again later.

Maybe someone in the general StackOverflow community will have some ideas but this is really for LinkedIn support, has they don't have there own support system and point people here!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as you say it's a question for LinkedIn support. They can't make it on-topic just by pointing people here.

Answer (score -1):

The issued turned out to be with Linked In on Edge, I tried on Chrome and it worked fine.